# Relational database management system

Tags: rdbms, database

If in a database with data in it, say for a column which is defined as char and it contains data in that column. If i change the column definition from char to number, will it allow to change? If yes, how it will effect the data present in the column?

Answer (score 0):

It will attempt to cast any content from char to number. If it can't on even one row, the change will fail. (This does depend on which DBMS you are using. I describe the ones I know; I don't know them all.)